# Example of double of topological space

Tags: general-topology

I am given the following definition for the double of a topological space.

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Define $D(X) = (X\times\{1\}) \cup (X \times \{2\})$. Then consider the basis of a topology on $D(X)$ by $\mathscr{B} = \{(U\times\{1\}) \cup(U\times\{2\} - \{(x,2)\}) : x\in X, U\subset X \text{ open}\} \cup \{(x,2): x\in X\} $.

I'm asked to show that $\mathscr{B}$ is actually a basis. It's an abstract definition, so I decided to work with a known example to see if I can figure something out. I picked my favorite space, the Sierpinski space. So, allow $X = \{x,y\}$ and let the topology be $\{\emptyset, \{y\}, \{x,y\}\}$.

So we have $D(X) = \{(x,1), (y,1), (x,2), (y,2)\}$. I calculated $$\mathscr{B} = \{ \emptyset, \{(y,2)\}, \{(x,2)\}, \{(y,1)\}, \{(y,1), (y,2)\}, \{(x,1), (y,1), (y,2)\}, \{(x,1), (y,1), (x,2)\} \} $$

I don't see how this is a basis. Let us consider the intersection of the last two elements I wrote in the basis. It is $\{(x,1), (y,1)\}$. In order for $\mathscr{B}$ to be a basis, we need another basis element which contains $(x,1)$ to be a subset of $\{(x,1), (y,1)\}$. But there is none!

Where did I go wrong in my example? Does $X$ actually need to be infinite for the double to exist?

Comment: It's really a description of local bases (so they combine to a base): the first for points of the form $(x,1)$ (so $x \in U$ is implicitly assumed) the second for points of the form $(x,2)$ (which have a one-set local base and $X \times \{2\}$ is discrete as a subspace, and the subspace is also open in $D(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base is made as follows: for $y \in X$ we have two open sets $\{y\}$ and $\{x,y\}$, and these give basic sets $\{(y,1)\}$ and $\{(y,1),(x,1),(x,2)\}$, for $x$ we only have the open set $\{x,y\}$ and this gives the set $\{(x,1), (y,1), (y,2)\}$. of the second type we have $\{(x,2)\}$ and $\{y,2)\}$. That's all.

The idea of the double is simple: points in $X \times \{1\}$ have their usual neighbourhoods doubled, but that would imply we cannot separate the points in the two copies, so we remove the doubled point itself, so that $D(X)$ will be Hausdorff if $X$ was. The second copy is just open discrete, but dense (if $X$ has no isolated points!).

Comment: Could you explain why $\{(y,1),(y,2)\}$ isn't in the base? It seems like it would be since we take $(U\times\{1\})\cup(U\times\{2\} -\{(x,2)\})$ where $U = \{y\}$. I must be interpreting something wrong.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain if $U=\{y\}$ that set is only $\{(y,1)\}$

Comment: I appreciate the clarification very much. It helps a lot.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain Glad it helped.